# Check if editor is currently focused with Slate

Tags: reactjs, slate

I'm trying to find a reliable way to find out if the slate editor is currenty focused or not. The editor should be in a focused state even when nested elements are selected.

I've tried

```
ReactEditor.isFocused(editor)
```

But am seing really inconsistent results. Often this will yield `true` even if the editor is not selected. Also, no rerender seems to be triggered when the editor focus changes.

Is there a reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `useFocused` hook from Slate?

https://docs.slatejs.org/libraries/slate-react#usefocused